# Changing and building parts of CyanogenMod

Tags: android, build, cyanogenmod, custom-rom

I have an assignment to take source code of **CyanogenMod** for certain device, to do some changes (at first, to disable tethering, set custom launcher that my team made, etc...). I managed to get source of CM, rebuilt it and flashed the device with it. I didn't use **LineageOS** deliberately, since its version is very unstable for this device.

Now, I wish to make some aforementioned adjustments and build ROM with these changes, could someone please point me to the right direction how to achieve it? I couldn't find anything similar to this on the net.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it's not too late:

you need to find your phone here :
https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/

and then go to https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/addison/build
(change addison by your device codeName, which you can find in the "DEVICES" part of this website)

you will find all instructions to build lineageos from sources for your phone, you can then modify these sources to add your custom launcher, disable anything you want...

Cheers